# How to add Welcome message to user for azure bot

Tags: botframework

Hi I found this sample code online. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

but i cant seem to use this code. is there a video on this topic about having welcoming message to new user on azure bot?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the team doesn't have any videos specifically on this topic, as the bleeding edge framework updates too quickly, and the video bits would probably quickly become obsolete or not the "best practice" to date. You say "I can't see to use this code." Post your code, what you've done, etc. so the community could help you get passed your problem